# I can't share a file from storage - "Can not attach an empty file"

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

The focus of my app is: create a PDF file, and share it at the Whatsapp, Messenger, Gmail, and others... But I'm trying to share the file (it's saved at **/storage/emulated/0/** ), but I returns an error for me on toast: "Can not attach an empty file.". The code of the method of share is below:

> MainActivity.java

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("*/*");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "NOME: ".concat(String.valueOf(Hawk.get("register_name"))));
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, String.valueOf(Hawk.get("register_name")).concat(" Business Card"));
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "test.com.br.businesscard.provider", new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "business.pdf")));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Sending e-mail..."));
```

> provider_paths.xml

```
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: "it's saved at /storage/emulated/0/ " -- be more specific. `getExternalFilesDir(null)` points to a specific location inside of external storage.

Comment: So how can I solve this? passing the location at the parameters of **getExternalFilesDir** ? like this: _new File(getExternalFilesDir("/storage/emulated/0/")_ , because it does not work :(

Comment: "So how can I solve this?" -- do you *literally* mean that the file is in `/storage/emulated/0`? If so, use `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "business.pdf")` to get the `File`.

Comment: Yeah!! It worked! Thank you, helped me a lot :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For files *directly* in `/storage/emulated/0`, the way to build the `File` is:

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ...)
```

where `...` is the filename of the file (e.g., `"business.pdf"`).

`getExternalFilesDir(null)` would be for files in a location like `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/.../`, where `...` is your application ID.

As it turns out, your `FileProvider` configuration would handle either location. However, `FileProvider` can't serve content using a `File` object pointing to a non-existent file, which is why you had problems.